# How did Ser Jorah do it this time?

Tags: game-of-thrones

**Season 6, episode 5, The Door:**

After

> Dany walks out of a big fire, again unscathed, she thanks Jorah for saving her life, presumably (but unsaid) *again*.

But in what way did he do so this time? In what way did he (and Daario, for that matter)

> save her?

It seems to me that they didn't really affect anything.

Comment: I think Dany walks out of that fire in Episode 4, not five? I could be wrong tho

Comment: @Aegon It is the end of episode 4 in which she walks out of the fire, but it is episode 5 in which she thanks Jorah for saving her life (again).

Comment: probably she is thanking him for taking down the son's of the harpy assassin when he comes back the second time

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Daenerys doesn't quite say that Jorah saved her life twice, merely that he has saved it at least once. It's not even clear that she is referencing any recent events. From "The Door":

> DAENERYS: I banished you twice. You came back twice. And you saved my life.

However, he arguably has saved her life *at least* twice.

### Jorah saved her from an assassin

In "You Win Or You Die," a wine merchant tried to offer Daenerys poisoned wine. Jorah exposed his attempt, thus saving Daenerys.  Admittedly, if not for his actions she would not have been targeted in the first place, but he saved her nonetheless.

### And from another assassin

In Season 5, Jorah threw a spear at a Son of the Harpy who had been creeping up behind Daenerys, intending to kill her.

Both of the previous examples are fairly clear-cut, but there's an argument that **he also saved her life more recently.**

### Jorah helped kill her enemies

True, Daenerys was the primary impetus behind the killing of the khals. Most of the credit for their deaths must go to her planning, not to mention her resistance to fire. By barring the door, however, Daario and Jorah ensured that none of the khals could escape the inferno. They also eliminated the khals' guard, thus depriving them of people who could have saved the khals, unbarred the door, put out the fire, or seized Daenerys. **Had the khals escaped, they most assuredly would have ordered Daenerys killed.** Thus, by preventing their escape, Jorah helped save Daenerys's life.

Comment: Until the last paragraph, I was thinking, "Yeah, but we already knew that." Your last paragraph was an AHA for me. Thanks, +1

Comment: @Jolenealaska, well, technically, the first few paragraphs dispute the premise of your question, so had you already known that, you wouldn't have asked (yes, I'm being incredibly and unnecessarily pedantic, sorry (not sorry)).

Comment: It has been a while, but was she not to also be kept as a Dosh Khaleen for the rest of her life, and  Jorah and Daario "rescued" her from that fate?

Comment: @APrough Yes, the Dothraki were, for all practical purposes, imprisoning her. She escaped and brought the Dothraki to her side as warriors primarily because she rocks. But, Jorah and Daario helped a lot.

Comment: There's also the fact that she flies away immediately after Jorah saves her in the Fighting Pits, and this is basically the first time they meet (apart from the short clandestine meeting before Dany goes into the house) under (somewhat) normal (and *formal*) circumstances, so it is the first time she has an opportunity to officially and formally thank and acknowledge him in public.